# html template with jquery

Tags: jquery, templates

I am trying to create a simple html template with jquery like this:

```
<div id="template" style="display: none">
   <div id="d1">1st line</div>
   <div id="d2">last line</div>
</div>

<div id="host"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var descriptions = [
    {'id': '1', 'author': 'Joe'},
    {'id': '2', 'author': 'Mary'},
    {'id': '3', 'author': 'Eric'}
];

// execute when page has fully loaded
window.onload = function () {
    var host = $("#host");
    var template = $("#template");

    for (var i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
        var description = descriptions[i];

        var id = "#" + description.id;
        console.log(id);
        template.find("div#d2").html(description.author);
        template.find("div#d1").attr("id", id);

        host.append(template.html());
    }
}
```

It works fine except the changing id part.
Each inserted part has the same id: "#1" but i can see the proper content in the console log: #1, #2, #3

```
<div id="host">
  <div id="**#1**">1st line</div>
  <div id="d2">Joe</div>
  <div id="**#1**">1st line</div>
  <div id="d2">Mary</div>
  <div id="**#1**">1st line</div>
  <div id="d2">Eric</div>
</div>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because in each iteration you're looking at the original `#template` element. The first iteration changes the `id` of the `#d1` element. In further iterations, the element is not found by the id selector (as you changed it) hence it's appended with the value of the first iteration.

To solve this you should `clone()` a new copy of `#template` in each iteration of the loop. Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var $host = $("#host");
    for (var i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
        var description = descriptions[i];
        var $template = $("#template").clone();
        $template.find("div#d2").text(description.author);
        $template.find("div#d1").prop("id", description.id);
        $host.append($template.html());
    }
};
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ofzyxqLn/)

Note that I removed the `#` from the value you set to the `id` attribute, as it will lead to confusion in your JS selectors and CSS rules. Also note the use of the `text()` and `prop()` methods over `html()` and `attr()`. You also could make full use of all jQuery's features by modifying your code to this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var $host = $("#host");
    $.each(descriptions, function(i, description) {
        var $template = $("#template").clone();
        $template.find("div#d2").text(description.author);
        $template.find("div#d1").prop("id", description.id);
        $host.append($template.html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any different between var $host = $("#host") and var host = $("#host") ? Sorry for this question but I aim a java guy am not good at JS.

Comment: No difference at all, the prepended `$` is just a naming convention to show that that variable holds a jQuery object.

Comment: No problem, glad to help